# Django throws ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: django, reactjs, api, websocket, django-rest-framework

Sorry in advance if my question looks obscure. This is the error thrown by Django when I'm trying to serve multiple Django media(videos) URLs in my React homepage.This is the stacktrace:

```
    Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 5511)
  File "D:\Django\myproject\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\Django\myproject\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Django\myproject\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "D:\Django\myproject\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

This is the React snippet:

```
<video 
 preload="metadata"
 id={this.props.id} 
 muted
 ref={this.videoRef}
 onClick={this.play.bind(this,1,this.props.id)} 
 onTimeUpdate={this.updateTime.bind(this,this.props.id)} 
 onCanPlay={this.getReady.bind(this,this.props.id)}> 
       <source src={this.props.source} type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
```

where video source refers to django media url provided by drf serializer.E.g

```
this.props.source = 'http://localhost:8000/media/buck_bunny.mp4'
```

The homepage contains multiple videos.The media URLs are fetched through API calls.Its a content feed page.Subsequent API calls to fetch media URLs are made when the user scrolls down the homepage for a certain amount. This is where the problem arises. If the user scrolls down very fast then API calls also get executed quickly leading to this error.

Comment: I hope the error did't break the code execution, have you created the project in virtualenv ?

Comment: Yes I ran it in a venv. It did hang my laptop.Do you have any idea why it happened?

Comment: Serving media files may need better server configuration, unlike image files .

Comment: I'm a newbie to web development. Sorry if the question seems irrelevant but do I have to configure it even if I'm running it on my local machine. If so then any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: faced above error once but in production the server did not break operation.

Comment: So you are telling that this error doesn't occur in production.

Comment: I found out that if I try this on Linux it might not break.But not too sure about it

Comment: for me it did not,

Comment: have you installed CORSHEADERS APP

Comment: Yes I did install it.

Comment: Wonder if this issue has something to do with windows 10.