# Django React js: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, reactjs, django, windows

I'm creating a web app using React in the frontend and Django in the backend. I used [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) blog to integrate react with backend. However I get a strange error called

```py
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I searched the internet a lot found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465300/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-a) question, did what the answer says but the problem persists. I don't think the database has something to do with my issue, because the pure django pages work fine but only react powered page throw this error. I found a question that is closest to  mine, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456075/django-throws-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection), but the question is unanswered, and apparently the problem is with loading some media page, but I just want to load `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`. Here's full traceback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ilqar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\ilqar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\ilqar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Ilqar\.virtualenvs\django-react-reddit-XsnOy92e\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ilqar\.virtualenvs\django-react-reddit-XsnOy92e\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request        
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\users\ilqar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

By the way, I did not include the code because it is exactly the same as in that blog.(except models and stuff, I don't do any api calls or something just `Hello World!`.

And I also tried to turn off firewall and try, but the result was the same, error is persisting.

I have `debug_toolbar` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` so it shows in the every page. Strangely only React side of page is not rendered, all the others, including debug toolbar, page title and stuff is there.
So what can I do about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and putting the `event.preventDefault();` in the submit event; I had no more problems